# How to make an internet call on phone from Android on a tablet

Tags: android

I am working on a custom embeded security system build on a Nexus 7 tablet. I would like to be able to automatically call my cell phone (later the 9-11) from my application. I don't know if it is possible. My guess is, that it is in theory.

So, anyone have an idea on how to make an internet call from Android program on a tablet?
Would it be complicated?
Is there a webservice I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making an Internet call requires `Session Initiation Protocol` Stack on your phone. This is available on Android phones with Gingerbread and above.

There is a detailed guide on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) .

It has all the code you need to make a call on `SIP over wifi.`

If you need a completely working code you can use [`Sipdroid`](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/) whose source code is open.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make phone calls from an android tablet(they don't have an antenna and receiver like cell phones). You might however be able to make Internet calls.  Look at this link for more info on [Internet](http://androidandme.com/2010/12/news/how-to-place-and-receive-internet-calls-with-android-2-3/) calling.

Comment: My mistake...I meant internet call on a phone.